# Can’t update the property of a child component from a parent component in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I’m newbie to React Native for mobile development. I’m using Expo. I can’t manage a state.

I have a `SearchTextBox` component, I want to set *text* property from the parent component, however I couldn’t manage it using `useState`.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View } from "react-native";

import defaultStyles from "../config/styles";

function SearchTextBox({
  searchQuery,
  width = "100%",
  onSearch,
  ...otherProps
}) {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState(searchQuery);
  const [isClearable, setIsClearable] = useState(
    query != null && query.length > 0
  );

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { text } = e.nativeEvent;
    setQuery(text);
    const length = text.length;
    setIsClearable(length > 0);
    if (length >= 2 && onSearch) onSearch(text);
  };

  const onClear = () => {
    setQuery("");
    setIsClearable(false);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View
        style={{
          width: 72,
        }}
      >
        <Ionicons
          name="md-search"
          size={32}
          color={defaultStyles.colors.medium}
          style={styles.icon}
        />
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          flex: 2,
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoFocus={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          placeholder="Search"
          placeholderTextColor={defaultStyles.colors.medium}
          style={[defaultStyles.text, styles.text]}
          onChange={onChange}
          value={query}
          {...otherProps}
        />
      </View>
      {isClearable && (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onClear}>
            <Ionicons
              name="md-close"
              size={32}
              color={defaultStyles.colors.medium}
              style={styles.icon}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: defaultStyles.colors.light,
    borderRadius: 24,
    flexDirection: "row",
    flex: 1,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  icon: {
    margin: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
  },
  text: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

export default SearchTextBox;
```

And I use like this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, FlatList, AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { AdMobBanner } from "expo-ads-admob";
import * as Device from "expo-device";

import { ListItem, ListItemSeparator } from "../components/lists/";
import Screen from "../components/Screen";
import SearchTextBox from "../components/SearchTextBox";
import AnimatedTextList from "../components/AnimatedTextList";

import colors from "../config/colors";

import searchApi from "../api/search";
import useApi from "../hooks/useApi";
import ads from "../config/ads";

function HomeScreen() {
  const search = useApi(searchApi.search);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [showRandomWords, setShowRandomWords] = useState(true);
  const [randomWords, setRandomWords] = useState([]);
  const [bannerType, setBannerType] = useState("banner");
  const [initialQuery, setInitialQuery] = useState();

  const getDeviceTypeAsync = async () => {
    const deviceType = await Device.getDeviceTypeAsync();
    setBannerType(
      deviceType === Device.DeviceType.TABLET ? "fullBanner" : "banner"
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getDeviceTypeAsync;
  }, []);

  const onSearch = async (value) => {
    setShowRandomWords(value == null || value == undefined || value === "");
    const result = await search.request(value);
    if (!result.ok) return;
    setData(result.data.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getRandomWords = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await AsyncStorage.getItem("random_words");
        if (!result) return;
        setRandomWords(JSON.parse(result));
        setShowRandomWords(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    getRandomWords();
  }, []);

  const bannerError = (error) => {
    console.log("An error occured while trying to show AdMob", error);
  };

  const onRandomWordPress = (item) => {
    setInitialQuery(item.title);
    onSearch(initialQuery);
  };

  return (
    <Screen>
      <View style={styles.searchBox}>
        <SearchTextBox
          searchQuery={initialQuery}
          width="90%"
          onSearch={onSearch}
        />
      </View>

      {showRandomWords && (
        <View>
          <AnimatedTextList items={randomWords} onPress={onRandomWordPress} />
        </View>
      )}

      <View style={styles.result}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(word) => word.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem title={item.word} subTitle={item.descp} />
          )}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bottomBanner}>
        <AdMobBanner
          style={styles.bottomBanner}
          bannerSize={bannerType}
          adUnitID={ads.unitID}
          servePersonalizedAds
          didFailToReceiveAdWithError={bannerError}
        />
      </View>
    </Screen>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bottomBanner: {
    alignContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    bottom: 0,
    position: "absolute",
    width: "100%",
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  searchBox: {
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    height: 100,
    width: "100%",
    padding: 10,
  },
  result: {
    width: "100%",
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

Here’s I bind the property

```js
<SearchTextBox
          searchQuery={initialQuery}
          width="90%"
          onSearch={onSearch}
        />
```

In `onRandomWordPress` I set the variable but however it doesn’t update the input’s text.

```js
const onRandomWordPress = (item) => {
    setInitialQuery(item.title);
    onSearch(initialQuery);
  };
```

What’s the proper way to do this or what’s wrong with my implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I achieved. I bind the query to a parent component (always), manage from parent for almost everything.

Now, I have a much cleaner `SearchTextBox` component.

```js
function SearchTextBox({
  searchQuery,
  onTextChange,
  onQueryClear,
  width = "100%",
  ...otherProps
}) {
  const hasSearchQuery = () => {
    return searchQuery != null && searchQuery.length > 0;
  };

  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { text } = e.nativeEvent;
    onTextChange(text);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View
        style={{
          width: 72,
        }}
      >
        <Ionicons
          name="md-search"
          size={32}
          color={defaultStyles.colors.medium}
          style={styles.icon}
        />
      </View>

      <View
        style={{
          flex: 2,
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          autoCorrect={false}
          autoFocus={false}
          autoCapitalize="none"
          placeholderTextColor={defaultStyles.colors.medium}
          style={[defaultStyles.text, styles.text]}
          onChange={onChange}
          value={searchQuery}
          {...otherProps}
        />
      </View>
      {hasSearchQuery() && (
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={onQueryClear}>
            <Ionicons
              name="md-close"
              size={32}
              color={defaultStyles.colors.medium}
              style={styles.icon}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

and manage part from parent:

```js
function HomeScreen() {
  const search = useApi(searchApi.search);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [showRandomWords, setShowRandomWords] = useState(true);
  const [randomWords, setRandomWords] = useState([]);
  const [initialQuery, setInitialQuery] = useState();

  const onSearch = async (value) => {
    const isEmptyQuery = value == null || value == undefined || value === "";
    setShowRandomWords(isEmptyQuery);
    const result = await search.request(value);
    if (!result.ok) return;
    setData(result.data.data);
  };

  const onQueryClear = () => {
    setInitialQuery("");
    setData([]);
    setShowRandomWords(true);
  };
  
  const onTextChange = (text) => {
    setInitialQuery(text);
    if (text.length > 2) onSearch(text);
  };

  const onRandomWordPress = (item) => {
    setInitialQuery(item.title);
    onSearch(item.title);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getRandomWords();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Screen>
      <View style={styles.searchBox}>
        <SearchTextBox
          searchQuery={initialQuery}
          onTextChange={onTextChange}
          onQueryClear={onQueryClear}
          width="90%"
        />
      </View>

      {showRandomWords && (
        <View>
          <AnimatedTextList items={randomWords} onPress={onRandomWordPress} />
        </View>
      )}

      <View style={styles.result}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          keyExtractor={(word) => word.id.toString()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem title={item.word} subTitle={item.descp} />
          )}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={ListItemSeparator}
        />
      </View>
    </Screen>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be passing the `random word` here to your `onSearch` function.

```
const onRandomWordPress = (item) => {
    setInitialQuery(item.title);
    onSearch(item.title);
};
```

Comment: it's same value. When search it's search correct because the search function occurs on the parent actually. It's just the property that not be set. So, the text input is empty in child component. But having results on parent. `onSearch` function works as expected.